# Use pandas to mark cell X if id in country

Tags: python, pandas

To start with, I have 3 Excel files, canada.xlsx, mexico.xlsx and usa.xlsx, each has 3 columns: id, a number, ColA, a text like Val1, and Country, each Excel file has only the country of its name in the third column, like only Canada in canada.xlsx

I make a df:

```
import pandas as pd  
import glob

savepath = '/home/pedro/myPython/pandas/xl_files/'  
saveoutputpath = '/home/pedro/myPython/pandas/outputxl/'  
# I put an extra column in each excel file named country with either Canada, Mexico or USA
filelist = glob.glob(savepath + "*.xlsx")

# open the xl files with the data  
# put all the data in 1 df   
df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(f) for f in filelist))  

# change the indexes to get unique indexes  
# df.index.size gets how many indexes there are  
indexes = []  
for i in range(df.index.size):
    indexes.append(i)
# now change the indexes pass a list to df.index
# never good to have 2 indexes the same
df.index = indexes
```

I make the output Excel, it has 4 columns, id, Canada, Mexico, USA. The point of the exercise is, write X in each country column with a corresponding id number, for example id 42345 may be in country Canada and Mexico, so 42345 should get an X in those 2 columns

I made this work, but I extracted the data from df to a dictionary. I tried various ways of doing this with df.loc() or df.iloc() but I can't seem to make it. I don't use pandas much.

This is the output df_out

```
# get a list of the ids
mylist = df["id"].values.tolist()
# get a set of the unique ids
myset = set(mylist)

#create new DataFrame with unique values in the column id
df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'USA'], index=range(0, len(myset)))
df_out.fillna(0, inplace=True)
# make a list of unique ids and sort them
id_names = list(myset)
id_names.sort()
# populate the id column with id_names
df_out["id"] = id_names
# see how many rows and columns
print(df_out.shape)

# mydict[key][0] is the id column , mydict[key][2]]is the country
for key in mydict.keys():    
    df_out.loc[df_out["id"] == mydict[key][0], mydict[key][2]] = "X"
```

Can you help me with a more "pandas way" of writing the X in df_out directly from df?

df:

```
        id   Col A country  
0    42345  Test 1     USA  
1   681593  Test 2     USA  
2   331574  Test 3     USA  
3    15786  Test 4     USA  
4    93512    Chk1  Mexico  
5   681593    Chk2  Mexico  
6   331574    Chk3  Mexico  
7    89153    Chk4  Mexico  
8    42345    Val1  Canada  
9    93512    Val2  Canada  
10  331574    Val3  Canada  
11   76543    Val4  Canada
```

df_out:

```
       id  Canada  Mexico  USA  
0   15786       0       0    0  
1   42345       0       0    0  
2   76543       0       0    0  
3   89153       0       0    0  
4   93512       0       0    0  
5  331574       0       0    0  
6  681593       0       0    0
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your input and desired output.  The explain what specific problem are you encountering.  Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='id', columns='country', aggfunc=lambda z: 'X', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Input

```
    id      country
0   42345   USA
1   681593  USA
2   331574  USA
3   15786   USA
4   93512   Mexico
5   681593  Mexico
6   331574  Mexico
7   89153   Mexico
8   42345   Canada
9   93512   Canada
10  331574  Canada
11  76543   Canada
```

Output

```
    id      Canada  Mexico  USA
0   15786       0        0    X
1   42345       X        0    X
2   76543       X        0    0
3   89153       0        X    0
4   93512       X        X    0
5   331574      X        X    X
6   681593      0        X    X
```